# Como Configurar Visual Studio 2015 Community Update 3 para trabajar con ES6 (archivos jsx)

Tags: visual-studio-2015, reactjs, ecmascript-2015

Buen día, estoy iniciándome en la librería react JS, quisiera saber como es la forma correcta de poder configurar visual studio 2015 community para que trabaje con react usando ES6 y también poder crear archivos jsx, ahora mismo el crear un archivo con esa extensión(.jsx) el IDE lo pinta en rojo como error de sintaxis.

He leído que para trabajar con ES6 se necesita de un transpilador (como Babel) para que el navegador pueda interpretar dicho código, y algunas otras configuraciones mas, pero todo ello lo hacen instalando diferentes paquetes pero por npm (osea tienes que tener node instalado). ¿Como se hace todo aquello pero para Visual Studio?

Gracias por su tiempo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En esta liga hay un proyecto de soporte

https://github.com/Microsoft/nodejstools/wiki/ES6-IntelliSense-Preview-in-NTVS-1.1

Requisito:

Tener las Herramientas de Node.js para Visual Studio descargables [aqui](https://github.com/Microsoft/nodejstools#readme) hay version para 2013 y 2015, hay que descargar la adecuada, ya que no hay retrocompatibilidad

Traducción de la instalación:

> Paso 1: Instalar TypeScript 1.6+
>
> Esta opción sólo estará habilitada si TypeScript  1.6 está instalado
>   para Visual Studio 2013 o 2015, actualmente disponible para su
>   descarga.
>
> ```
>   Nota: TypeScript 1.8 es necesario para versiones preliminares.
> ```
>
> Paso 2: Seleccione la opción "ES6 IntelliSense Preview"
>
> Para una vista previa de esta nueva experiencia debe seleccionar la
>   opción "ES6 IntelliSense Preview" * que se encuentra en Visual Studio
>   en: `Herramientas> Opciones> Editor de texto> Node.js> IntelliSense` o
>   `Tools > Options > Text Editor > Node.js > IntelliSense`
>
> [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
>
> Paso 3: Cierre todos los archivos JavaScript abiertos
>
> Después de seleccionar esta opción, deberá cerrar y volver a abrir los
>   archivos JavaScript que se están editando antes de que entre en vigor
>   el cambio.

Comment: ya instale TypeScript para VS, pero a la hora de dirigirme a tools > Options > Text Editor, no tengo la opción Node.js, sin embargo, si tengo instaldo node en mi equipo, cuento con la versión v6.7.0, ¿sabes si tiene que ver algo la versión de visual studio?, porque yo uso VS 2015 Community Update 3

Comment: @MichaelV. creo que ten falta el plugin para nodejs de visual studio, purdes bajarlo aqui https://github.com/Microsoft/nodejstools#readme

Comment: tenias razón, si me faltaba el plugin del node js para visual studio, ya visualizo la opción del intellisense del ES6.

Comment: una consulta adicional, ¿sabes de algún website que indique los pasos para poder trabajar con archivos jsx cuando se trabaja con react y visual studio?, según leo microsoft indica que se puede trabajar con React.js Starter Kit v0.2.0.vsix

Comment: @MichaelV. Ahi si te fallo, no trabajo con react :(

Comment: agradezco tu tiempo y apoyo :-)